Is there a better way to allow only one concurrent camel route execution and discard additional requests while route is running?
Objective:

I want to run camel route that takes long time to complete. I want to
start this route with put request.
I want to allow only 1 concurrent
executions for that route.
I want to discard any other request that
arrive while route is still processing. I don't want to queue them to
process later, just discard.

After trying everything I could come up with I ended up having the following code that uses AtomicBoolean to remember if it is currently processing something or not. But it seems a bit hack to me. Given requirements above, am I supposed to solve it like that or does camel offer any better way?
@Component
public class TestRoute2 extends RouteBuilder {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @Override
  public void configure() {

    AtomicBoolean isProcessing = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    from("platform-http:/api/myservice?httpMethodRestrict=PUT")
      .routeId("myServiceRoute")
      .doTry()
        .process(exchange -> {
        // Cast the endpoint to SedaEndpoint to access the queue
        SedaEndpoint sedaEndpoint = (SedaEndpoint)
        getContext().getEndpoint("seda:handlePut");
        int currentQueueSize = sedaEndpoint
          .getQueue()
          .size();

        if (currentQueueSize > 0 || isProcessing.get()) {
          throw new org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException("Service busy", exchange);
        }

        // Mark service as busy
        isProcessing.set(true);
      })
        .wireTap("seda:handlePut")
        .setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", constant(204))
      .endDoTry()
      .doCatch(org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException.class)
      .setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", constant(503))
      .setBody(constant("Service busy, please try again later"))
      .end();

    from("seda:handlePut?concurrentConsumers=1")
      .doTry()
        .bean(myService, "slowMethod") // runs for long time
      .endDoTry()
      .doFinally()
      .process(exchange -> isProcessing.set(false));
  }
}

Before that I also tried the following code. It doesn't use AtomicBoolean which seems improvement from clean code point of view but the problem is that it still queues 1 extra request before it starts giving 503 back. This means that n PUT requests to /api/myservice endpoint while handlePut is running will cause 1 extra execution of handlePut route that will be executed after initial handlePut is finished but I want 0 extra executions.
  @Override
  public void configure() {

    from("platform-http:/api/myservice?httpMethodRestrict=PUT")
      .routeId("myServiceRoute")
      .doTry()
        .process(exchange -> {
        SedaEndpoint sedaEndpoint = (SedaEndpoint)
        getContext().getEndpoint("seda:handlePut");
        int currentQueueSize = sedaEndpoint
          .getQueue()
          .size();
        if (currentQueueSize > 0) {
          throw new org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException("Service busy", exchange);
        }
      })
        .wireTap("seda:handlePut")
        .setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", constant(204))
      .endDoTry()
      .doCatch(org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException.class)
        .setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", constant(503))
        .setBody(constant("Service busy, please try again later"))
      .end();

    from("seda:handlePut?concurrentConsumers=1")
      .bean(myService, "slowMethod");
  }

Is this code that uses AtomicBoolean the way it should be done or does camel have any more correct way?

Did you try the Threads EIP configured with maxPoolSize=1, maxQueueSize=0 and rejectedPolicy=Abort?

Could you tell where to put them? from("seda:handlePut?concurrentConsumers=1&maxPoolSize=1&maxQueueSize=0&rejectedPolicy=Abort") does not seem to be correct. It says Unknown optionfor all 3 of them.

Add .threads(1).maxPoolSize(1).maxQueueSize(0).rejectedPolicy(ThreadPoolRejectedPolicy.Abort) after the from endpoint.

Thanks, that helped me to get closer to my objective. But now how do I know when to return error response to rest client without making it to wait? If I use to("seda:handlePut") in first route then rest client will have to wait 2nd route finishes. But If I use .wireTap("seda:handlePut") then this RejectedExecutionExceptionis also thrown in a separate thread and I can't catch it in first route to return error response.

You can just check the inflight registry, and if its > 1 then return a http server busy status code or something.

Could you provide sample code?

No I cannot do that
